# Cannot recognize type (double complex)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

### VS Code Windows

An error occurs while I was defining a C method (not C++) using variable

`double complex *a_t`.

However, VS Code cannot recognize type double complex. Instead, the system recognizes double as a type and complex as merely a variable name.

[image]

How do I fix this problem? Is it because the system automatically C++ as primary tool, which defines a complex number using complex < double > XXX?

### Problem Update

I used to code on VSCode in linux, and I am using a library called **libcint**.

Lately, I was gonna move and code it to my windows system, but VSCode reported that it cannot recognize the function variable of all `double complex XXX`, it seems the system recognize `complex` as a variable of type `double` instead of explaining `double complex` as a available type.

I tried to check my complex header file **<complex.h>** and found there was no defination about `complex`. I treid to revise the function variable as `double _Complex`, which can be successfully recognized, so I then went `#define complex _Complex` in the library's main header file. However, some functions like `conj()` are therefore failed to be called since in this complex file, the function is expecting type `_Dcomplex`.

All the functions and compile process were passed in linux(see below compile process). After comparing the two different <complex.h>, I suspect that they are using different complex files--Windows introduces Microsoft one and linux is using ISO C99.

In my linux system, this claim is shown in <complex.h>

```
 /*
 *  ISO C99:  7.3 Complex arithmetic    <complex.h>
 */
```

Then I tried add `#set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "std=c99")` and `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_ENABLE_C99}")` in libcint's CMakeList, and still doesnot work.

### Compiling Process

About the Compiling, I followed the instruction on https://github.com/sunqm/libcint, which uses

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>
make install
```

to accomplish the compiling process.

### So Far

After checking the comment box and Microsoft at [Specify Language Standard Version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-160), I suspect that VSCode's plugin does not support ISO C99 standard, but is it correct that I still can compile it through gcc in cmd?

Comment: Do you mean to use `std::complex<double>` rather than `double complex`?

Comment: @Chrsi so is your question that you're trying to use C complex types but due to VSCode thinking you have a C++ file you're getting this error?

Comment: Does your file compile? Do you have `#include <complex.h>`? Note that 'typeerror' tag is not appropriate here either. A type error is a very specific kind of error. The tool detects a syntax error, even though it has something to do with types.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I assume so, do you know how to correctly define a complex number in C? I have seen a lot libraries defined in this way.

Comment: @Chrsi if you're including `<complex.h>` then this should be fine, otherwise you have to replace `complex` with `_Complex`.

Comment: @Chrsi who said that C++ `defines a complex number using double* XXX`? In C++ it's `std::complex`. And **VS code doesn't know anything about complex** because it's just a text editor, not compiler. It depends on your compiler (which you didn't show) to know the complex type

Comment: @phuclv VS Code knows about complex via the language plugin (née intellisense), which is totally separate from the compiler.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Thanks, and that's why I think it's wired since I added the head file <complex.h>

Comment: @Chrsi then it's probably some plugin issue with VSCode. Does your plugin support C complex types (I thinkt the default C intellisense plugin does though)? And is your file recognized as a C file (I think there's a blue bar at the bottom which tells which language it thinks your file is)? In a previous comment you said your file name is something like XXX.C. Is the C in that capital? Because if it is then it's probably being interpreted as a C++ file.

Comment: If you're using the Microsoft C compiler, it doesn't understand C99 complex numbers.

Comment: @Shawn Which version of C do you recommend?

Comment: @Shawn who said that? [MSVC supports C11 and C17](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c11-and-c17-standard-support-arriving-in-msvc/). The only unsupported C99 feature is VLA which can be easily done with [`alloca()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @phuclv C11 and C17 are not C99, and many people don't use the latest version of Visual Studio tools to get what features are supported. Plus, relevant for this question, from your link, *Support for Complex numbers is currently not planned and their absence is enforced with the proper feature test macros.* All the other things that were made optional in C11 to cater to MS are also not supported according to it.

Comment: @Shawn [MSVC does support C complex numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support?view=msvc-160)

Comment: Interestingly, [complex number functions paralleling the standard ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support?view=msvc-160) appear to be provided; but they work with MS-specific types instead of standard ones.

Comment: @phuclv *The compiler does not directly support a `complex` or `_Complex` keyword, therefore the Microsoft implementation uses structure types to represent complex numbers.*

Comment: Hmm. Wouldn't be too hard to come up with a set of macros that resolve to the correct thing depending on if standard C complex numbers or MS-specific complex numbers are being used so that you can use the same (Slightly ugly) code in both environments.

Comment: @Shawn Could you illustrate the method? I never used macros before.

Answer (score 2):

While MSVC does [support the <complex.h> header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/complex-math-support), its implementation uses a `struct` internally and is therefore not compliant with standard C.

If you need to support both compliant compilers and MSVC within the same codebase, you can use macros and `typedef`s that will expand to either the standard types and functions or MSVC's ones. You also need to write functions (which will be simple wrappers on compliant compilers) to handle the standard `+ - * /` operators.

Thankfully, most of the MSVC's functions have the same names as the [standard C ones](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex), e.g. `cabs()`, `creal()`, `ctan()`... However, you will not be able to use the `+ - * /` on complex numbers (since these are not native types on MSVC) and you need to roll your own, except for `*` which is provided as `_Cmulcc()`. There is also an MSVC's equivalent of C11 [`CMPLX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/CMPLX), [`_Cbuild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/cbuild-fcbuild-lcbuild), to construct complex numbers from their real and imaginary parts.

Here is a minimal example that adds two complex numbers together and prints the result. It compiles and runs successfully on recent versions of MSVC, GCC and Clang:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER // using Microsoft's implementation:

// there is also _Fcomplex for float complex and _Lcomplex for long double complex
typedef _Dcomplex double_complex;
#define mk_dbl_cmplx _Cbuild

// we need this on MSVC since it does not support the '+' operator:
double_complex add_dbl_cmplx (double_complex a, double_complex b)
{
    return mk_dbl_cmplx(creal(a) + creal(b), cimag(a) + cimag(b));
}

#else // using standard C:

typedef double complex double_complex;
#define mk_dbl_cmplx CMPLX

// on a compliant compiler, it is a simple wrapper around the + operator:
double_complex add_dbl_cmplx (double_complex a, double_complex b)
{
    return a + b;
}

#endif


char *sprint_complex (char *str, double_complex x)
{
    sprintf(str, "%g + %g * i", creal(x), cimag(x));
    return str;
}

int main (void)
{
    double_complex a = mk_dbl_cmplx(3, -7);
    double_complex b = mk_dbl_cmplx(2, 5);

    double_complex c = add_dbl_cmplx(a, b);

    printf("(%s) + (%s) = (%s)",
        sprint_complex((char[32]){""}, a),
        sprint_complex((char[32]){""}, b),
        sprint_complex((char[32]){""}, c)
    );
}
```

Compiled with MSVC, GCC or Clang, this should output:

```
(3 + -7 * i) + (2 + 5 * i) = (5 + -2 * i)
```